# Why am I not able to access the storage of a contract deployed with bytecode?

Tags: contract-development, evm, bytecode, deployed-bytecode

I'm learning about EVM and I was trying to write a simple smart contract using bytecode only. What the contract is supposed to do is write the number `202` to `storage slot 0` read from the storage and return the value. When I deploy the contract and make a call to it, it correctly returns 202, but for some reason when I use `web3.eth.getStorageAt(<address>,0)` it `returns 0x0`. Why is that?
I'm using ganache to test the contract and `getStorageAt` works with a regular solidity contract but not with the one deployed with bytecode.

```
0x601080600b6000396000f360ca60005560005460005260206000f3
```

---

```
[1] PUSH1 0x10
[2] DUP1
[4] PUSH1 0x0b
[6] PUSH1 0x00
[7] CODECOPY
[9] PUSH1 0x00
[10] RETURN
[12] PUSH1 0xca
[14] PUSH1 0x00
[15] SSTORE
[17] PUSH1 0x00
[18] SLOAD
[20] PUSH1 0x00
[21] MSTORE
[23] PUSH1 0x20
[25] PUSH1 0x00
[26] RETURN
```

Comment: I've tested your code using https://www.evm.codes/playground but it looks fine. Maybe you are trying getStorageAt using a wrong address?